# How to stop steam at startup in windows 10

Tags: steam, windows, windows-10

I have steam installed in my laptop and it is annoying that steam is starting automatically when my system starts. I have unchecked the option "**Run Steam when my computer runs**" and disabled from startup programs in task manager as well. Is there anything else I could do to stop this?

[image]

Comment: Do you close properly steam before shutting down your computer ?
It seems that, with the new Windows versions, even though you ask the computer to shutdown, it's not a "real" shutdown. 
When that happens, I find out that my applications (Steam, Chrome, Outlook, etc.) reopen on their own.

Comment: I click "Exit Steam", followed by "Shut down" in power menu of windows start menu. I think I am doing it right, ain't I?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was wondering. Then I'm clueless. Another software might be starting Steam (like, if you try to run a Steam game while Steam is closed, Steam opens automatically).

Comment: Even I couldn't find what is starting it and how to stop it. It makes my system a bit slower everytime I restart.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling Steam? Unchecking the "Run Steam When My computer Starts" really should take care of this... since it isn't, I wonder if something else is corrupt in the background

Comment: Recommending checking out your Task Scheduler. Sometimes tasks can get created in there to run actions on logon. Not likely the case here, but it doesn't hurt to check.

Comment: Tell us more about the user account you use to log in to Windows when it boots up.  Are you an administrator?  Is yours the only user on the computer?  When you installed Steam, do you recall if you installed it "for all users" or just for your user?  I'm thinking maybe some sort of permissions issue is preventing Windows from allowing the status change to the Steam service.  Also double-check in task manager if the changes you made there actually stuck after a reboot.

Comment: Do you mean "Task Manager" with "task bar"?

Comment: Are you running any Steam apps on startup?  Starting any of Steam's apps will start Steam.

Comment: Do you have any [Utilities](https://store.steampowered.com/tags/en/Utilities/) bought through Steam installed?

Comment: You mean apps/games? Yes i bought counter strike and installed it. Is that causing any issue?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean the Task Manager (if not: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>  Start-up  *Steam Client Bootstrapper*, <kbd>Right-click</kbd>, 'Disable'), **try disabling the Steam service**:

In the Start menu, type `services`, and open the Windows Services app.
In the list showing up, look for *Steam Client Service*, <kbd>Right-click</kbd> it, select *Properties*, and set *Startup Type* to 'Manual'.

Comment: Checked the services as well. It is **manual** already! :(